# Trying to do 3 different inset procedure in oracle but I'm getting errors and can't figure it out

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, procedure

What I'm trying to do is create a package that has insert, delete and update for each my tables. and I have 3 tables. I write inserts for each table and its works in Kategori named table but others keep giving the same errors. I'm a student and it's my first database lecture. I would be grateful if someone helps me.

```
    create or replace package xx_Şirket_pkg
    as
    procedure kategori_Insert_prc(KategoriNo number, İsim varchar2);
    procedure calisan_Insert_prc(ŞirketNo number, ÇalışanNo number,Çalışanİsim varchar2);
    procedure şirket_Insert_prc(ŞirketNo number, KategoriNo number,ŞirketAdı varchar2,Açıklama varchar2, GenelMüdür varchar2,Tarih number);
    procedure kategori_delete_prc(p_KategoriNo number);
    procedure calisan_delete_prc(p_ÇalışanNo number);
    procedure şirket_delete_prc(p_ŞirketNo number);
    end xx_Şirket_pkg;
    
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xx_Şirket_pkg
    AS
    procedure kategori_Insert_prc(KategoriNo number, İsim varchar2)
    IS 
    Begin 
    INSERT INTO Kategori values (KategoriNo, İsim);
    End kategori_Insert_prc;
    
    procedure calisan_Insert_prc(ŞirketNo number, ÇalışanNo number, Çalışanİsim varchar2)
    IS 
    Begin 
    INSERT INTO Calisanlar values (ŞirketNo, ÇalışanNo, Çalışanİsim);
    End calisan_Insert_prc;
    
    procedure şirket_Insert_prc(ŞirketNo number, KategoriNo number,ŞirketAdı varchar2,Açıklama varchar2, GenelMüdür varchar2,Tarih number)
    IS 
    Begin 
    INSERT INTO Şirket values (ŞirketNo, KategoriNo,ŞirketAdı,Açıklama, GenelMüdür,Tarih);
    End şirket_Insert_prc;
    
    procedure kategori_delete_prc(p_KategoriNo number)
    IS 
    Begin 
    Delete Kategori where KategoriNo= p_KategoriNo;
    End kategori_delete_prc;
    
    
    procedure calisan_delete_prc(p_ÇalışanNo number)
    IS 
    Begin 
    Delete Calisanlar where ÇalışanNo= p_ÇalışanNo;
    End calisan_delete_prc;
    
    
    procedure şirket_delete_prc(p_ŞirketNo number)
    IS 
    Begin 
    Delete Şirket where ŞirketNo= p_ŞirketNo;
    End şirket_delete_prc;
    
    End xx_Şirket_pkg;
```

when I try to run this

```
begin
xx_Şirket_pkg.calisan_Insert_prc(5, Calisanlar_ÇalışanNo_seq.nextval ,'Yakup');
End;
```

I'm getting this error

```
ORA-00917: missing comma
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.XX_ŞIRKET_PKG", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I can't find it
also when I run this

```
begin
xx_Şirket_pkg.şirket_Insert_prc(Şirket_ŞirketNo_seq.nextval, 1,'Yakup','Yakup', 'Yakup',190);
End;
```

I'm getting this error message

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.XX_ŞIRKET_PKG", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 2 this
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong in code you posted. However, I'm not sure how Oracle interprets non-English alphabet characters you used in various names (columns, tables, procedures).

I'm Croatian and we also have some *local* characters that don't exist in English alphabet; here's what I get if I try to use them:

```
SQL> create table ćačaš (žuđ number);
create table ćačaš (žuđ number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character


SQL>
```

Apparently, Oracle doesn't like that. Are you **sure** you can use characters you used with no problems? How did you create those tables/columns? Did you, by any chance, enclose them into double quotes? Such as

```
SQL> create table "ćačaš" ("žuđ" number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

If you did, then you'll have to use them (double quotes, along with exactly matched letter case) every time.

---

I do have some other objections, though:

- it seems you created your objects in `SYSTEM` schema. That's **very wrong**. Never, ever do anything but system maintenance using `SYS` or `SYSTEM`. They *own* the database and - if you do something wrong - you'll *destroy* your database. Create your own user and practice your programming skills in that schema.
- in `insert`, always name all columns you're inserting into, e.g.

  ```
  INSERT INTO Kategori (category, isim) VALUES (KategoriNo, Isim);
                       ----------------
                       this
  ```
- name parameters while calling procedures:

  ```
  BEGIN
     xx_sirket_pkg.calisan_Insert_prc (
        sirketno     => 5,
        calisanno    => calisanlar_calisanno_seq.NEXTVAL,
        calisanisim  => 'Yakup');
  END;
  ```

Comment: That's was very helpful thanks. I think I will create everything from scratch. All the tables and stuff because I get confused about those errors and can't fix them. This time I'm not gonna use any local characters. It was my first question in StackOverflow and that was a very welcoming experience thanks to you :)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you'll make it work.